# $Hom_{Ab}(A,-)$ is not strongly additive for some $A\in Obj(Ab)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

This is an exercise question in Dold Algebraic Topology, Chpt VI, 2.12. The point is to demonstrate that additive functors does not preserve infinite direct sums.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the example showing that $Hom_{Ab}(A,-)$ does not preserving infinite direct sums? I tried $A=Z_4, Z_2$ with $-=\oplus Z_4, \oplus Z_2$. However, it seems I cannot get something uncountable out by taking a countable finite direct sums. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: You need to take $A$ to be infinitely generated.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe this is a dumb question. I followed your hint to consider $\oplus Hom(\oplus Z,Z)\cong\oplus\prod Hom(Z,Z)\to Hom(\oplus Z,\oplus Z)\cong\prod Hom(Z,\oplus Z)$. So this boils down to $\oplus\prod Z\to \prod\oplus Z$ is not surjection. I think the essential point is to see $\oplus Hom(\oplus Z, Z)\to Hom(\oplus Z,\oplus Z)$ is not surjection by following. There is more elements in $Hom(\oplus Z,\oplus Z)$.(Every element of $\oplus Z$ is finite combintation but each $f$'s image being finite sum does not imply $f$ is finite sum of functions of $Hom(\oplus Z,Z)$.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is above idea correct? Thank.